# Can i write like that

Tags: bdd, specflow

```
Scenario: Given CADD is greater than 0 and applicant confirmed as previous occupant at current   address then match strength is IO  
Given The Response contains "AC09>0"  
And   "Neaa01=0" or "NDac01=1"  
When  I fire the request  
Then  The Match strength should be "IO"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this topic before you go any further: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is that actual question?  Are you asking if this is a valid secnario?

Comment: Yes sam is this valid scenario?

Comment: seems like its ok from a specflow point of view...  Does it describe your business scenario?

Comment: yes according to acceptance criteria

Answer (score 1):

No and No.

This would ALMOST be a valid scenario in SpecFlow in terms of the parser would be able to handle it and you could run this test except that have used an `or` in the 2nd `Given` (the `And`). This really makes it two different scenarios.

```
Given The Response contains "AC09>0"  
And   "Neaa01=0" 
When  I fire the request  
Then  The Match strength should be "IO"  

Given The Response contains "AC09>0"  
And   "NDac01=1"  
When  I fire the request  
Then  The Match strength should be "IO"
```

However as part of a BDD process this is very poor. Your aim should be to have a scenario that is in business langugae and you can imagine two non-technical people discussiing. I just don't ever see somebody saying "Neaa01=0" out loud.

And yet the description of the scenario you give is actually a far better example

```
Given CADD is greater than 0 
and applicant confirmed as previous occupant at current address 
then match strength is IO
```

If you could rephrase the `Given CADD is greater than 0` then it would be quite neat.

Don't forget that SpecFlow's role is to turn the business language into something runnable, e.g.

```
[Given("applicant confirmed as previous occupant at current address")
public void ApplicantConfirmedAsPreviousOccupantAtCurrentAdddress()
{
   Request.Neaa01=0;
}
```